# How to find the angle of a vector based on origin?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How can I find the angle between a vector and unit vector [1, 0], but I don't want the shortest angle, but always the right side angle like this:

```
[1, 0] -> 0
[0, 1] -> PI/2
[-1, 0] -> PI
[0, -1] -> 3 * PI / 2
```

I've tried `arctan(y/x)` but what if `x` is 0 what happens then?

Comment: If $x=0$ and $y>0$ then roughly speaking $\arctan(y/x)=\arctan(\infty)=\pi/2.$ You just have to tackle that case individually.

Comment: you shall not be able to pass infinity around like that into functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly, you need to compute $\arctan(y/x)$. To be more precise, you also need to work out which quadrant the angle is in. Many programming languages have a function $\texttt{arctan2}(x,y)$ that does all this for you.

Comment: but what if x is 0 how can I divide then